# Reach a primefaces gmap inside a pf p:dialog using javascript

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a p:gmap inside a p:dialog

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="vehicleTrackingDlg" rendered="#{sessionBean.vehicleTracking}" 
              width="630" height="405" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)" resizable="false" header="Map">
        <p:gmap id="map" center="30, 20" zoom="13" type="ROADMAP" fitBounds="true" 
                style="width:600px;height:400px" widgetVar="gmap" rendered="#{sessionBean.vehicleTracking}" /> 
</p:dialog>
```

I'm trying to get the 'gmap' variable in a javascript file 'initialize()' function.

```js
function initialize()
{
    map = PF('gmap').getMap();

    directionsService = new  google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    markerMe = new google.maps.Marker({title: "Ben"});

    markerSelectedVehicle = new google.maps.Marker();
    var image = '../resources/images/favicon_red.ico';
    markerSelectedVehicle.setIcon(image);
}
```

map variable in the javascript file is not initialized this way.
If i take the p:gmap out of p:dialog it works fine.
How can i reach p:gmap inside the p:dialog.
Is it about p:gmap is not initialized since p:dialog is not invoked in the javascript initialize() phase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you remove the rendered attributes

Comment: The Condition is 'true' in my attempts . When i get the p:gmap out of  p:dialog it works but the map is in a random place in the page.

Comment: How is sessionBean.vehicleTracking being set to true, is it always true or being set to true based on something the user does on the page? From where is initialize() called?

Comment: It's not true by default but the condition in my tests is true since the user has the privilege to see the map related menus. initialize() is called via google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); in the window load. As i stated it works fine when the p:gmap is out of p:dialog. may it be about syntax when trying to reach widgetvar of p:gmap inside widgetvar of p:dialog?

Comment: You can just test syntax and wether or not its there in the console in firebug. I would say syntax is the same no matter if in dialog or not. A collegue has run into problems when adding a window-load listener as he cannot choose if it should run before or after the PF load-stuff. I'd say yours should run after but I don't know if thats your problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment or two to get ready – this means that when a $(function() { } );  document ready call happens, the widgets might not be ready yet.

Surround your code in `$(function() { } );` like this in [enter link description here](http://knowles.co.za/primefaces-where-are-my-widgets/)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 

    var map = PF('gmap').getMap();

    directionsService = new  google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    markerMe = new google.maps.Marker({title: "Ben"});

    markerSelectedVehicle = new google.maps.Marker();
    var image = '../resources/images/favicon_red.ico';
    markerSelectedVehicle.setIcon(image);

} );
</script>
```